# Infinite linear independent family in a finitely generated $A$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

So I'm stuck with this problem.

Let $A$ be a nonzero commutative ring (with unit). I have several questions that are really close to each other.

1) Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over $A$. Can we have $\{x_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subset M$ a linear independent family in $M$ ?

2) Let $M$ be a module over $A$ generated by $f_1, \ldots, f_n \in M$. Can we have $x_1,\ldots, x_{n+1} \in M$ a linear independent family ? (Obviously a negative answer to the latter implies a negative answer to the former.)

3) Let $N$ be a free module over $A$, and $M$ a module such that there exists an exact sequence $0 \to N \to M$ and another exact sequence $N \to M \to 0$. Is $M$ a free module as well (is $M \simeq N$)? If not, can we add $N$ of finite rank to get a positive answer ?

4) Let $M$ be finitely generated by $f_1, \ldots, f_n$, and $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be a linear independent family in $M$. Is $M$ free?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: In (3), are you assuming that the modules are finitely generated? Since if they aren't, the statement must not necessarily be true. To see this, take as $N$ a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module with countable base and for $M$ a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space with countable base.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the key words are [onto endomorphisms are isomorphisms](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2316897?uid=3737528&uid=2129&uid=2134&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21102965860601). (Actually, the paper proves more than the title says!)

2) The answer is negative and as you remarked this also solves 1). Let $F$ be the submodule of $M$ generated by $x_1,\dots, x_{n+1}$. We have an isomorphism $F\to A^{n+1}$. Since $M$ is generated by $n$ elements there exists $K\le A^n$ such that $A^n/K\to M$ is an isomorphism. Now take the canonical projection $p:A^{n+1}\to A^n$ which sends $(a_1,\dots,a_{n+1})$ to $(a_1,\dots,a_{n})$, and thus we get an onto homomorphism $F\to M$. This must be an isomorphism, and we get that $p$ is injective, a contradiction.

4) Yes, it is! Use similar arguments as above to get that $M\cong A^n$.

3) This follows immediately from Orzech's Theorem.

**Remark.** A proof of Orzech's result can be found on M.SE in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1066110/121097).

(Another proof of these questions, based on McCoy's Theorem, can be found in [this paper](http://www2.im.uj.edu.pl/actamath/PDF/30-215-218.pdf).)

Comment: Sorry I didn't checked the answer yet, I had a busy weekend... by onto homomorphism, do you mean surjective $A$-linear map? So because M is generated by $ n $ elements I have a surjective map $A^{n}$ and because $F$ is isomorph to $A^{n+1}$ I get another surjective map from $F $ to $ A^{n }$ I compose the two and that's your onto homomorphism from $ F $ to $ M $ ? I can't understand why you tell me about $ K $... thanks for your quick answer though :)

Comment: @jeanmfischer As you could have seen in the first link I gave you, onto = epi = surjective. On the other side, I don't understand your trouble with $K$ as long as a module is finitely generated iff there exists a surjective (or onto, if you like it) homomorphism $A^n\to M$ (for some $n$) iff $M$ is isomorphic to a quotient of a free module of finite rank, that is, $M\cong A^n/K$ (for some $n$ and some $K$).