# Is Orzech's generalization of the surjective-endomorphism-is-injective theorem correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

In [math.stackexchange answer #239445](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/239445/586), Makoto Kato quoted a statement from the paper

> Morris Orzech, *Onto Endomorphisms are Isomorphisms*, Amer. Math. Monthly 78 (1971), 357--362.

The statement (Theorem 1 in said paper) claims that if $A$ is a commutative ring, if $M$ is a finitely-generated $A$-module, if $N$ is an $A$-submodule of $M$, and if $f : N \to M$ is a surjective $A$-linear map, then $f$ is also injective.

This claim generalizes the well-known fact that a surjective endomorphism of a finitely-generated $A$-module is injective (which appears, e.g., as Lemma 10.15.4 in the Stacks project, Version 5b422bc, compiled on Nov 05, 2014 -- the numbering will probably change but it is Lemma {lemma-fun} in [algebra.tex](https://github.com/stacks/stacks-project/blob/master/algebra.tex) -- and I am citing this because the Stacks project has an interesting alternative proof of this fact). Orzech's proof first deals with the case of $A$ noetherian and then reduces the general case to it. Unfortunately, the reduction step is wrong: the map $f$ is applied to elements of $M$ which are not known to belong to $N$. (The proof in Orzech's paper is the same as the one in Kato's post.)

Is the claim itself true for non-Noetherian $A$ ? I cannot even prove the $M = A$ case, nor can I obtain a counterexample from the usual suspects (polynomials in infinitely many variables, or idempotent variables, or nilpotent variables).

Comment: note that the person who first gave the reference was http://math.stackexchange.com/users/619/kcd

Comment: @Darij: The stacks project provides tags which are version-independent; they can even be used in papers. See http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tags for further information. Here it's Tag 05G8. Great question by the way; I really wondered about that statement when I heard of it recently.

Comment: I think the proof of the Noetherian case is also flawed. $f^n$ doesn't make sense there.

Comment: Proof when $M=A$: Choose $n \in N$ with $f(n)=1$. If $f(x)=0$, then $0=f(x)n=f(xn)=f(n)x=x$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module and $N$ be an $A$-submodule of $M$. Let $f\colon N \rightarrow M$ be a surjective homomorphism of $A$-modules. Then $f$ is injective.

Proof. Let $0 \neq x'_0 \in N$. It suffices to prove $f(x'_0) \neq 0$. 
Set $f(x'_0) = x_0$.

Let $x_1, \dots, x_n$ be generators for $M$. Then $x'_0=\sum_{i=1}^na'_ix_i$ and $x_0=\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i$.

Let $x'_i\in N$ such that $f(x'_i) = x_i$ and write $x'_i = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} a_{ij} x_j$.

Let $A' = \mathbb{Z}[a_{ij}, a_{i}, a'_i]$. $A'$ is a Noetherian subring of $A$.

Let $N' = A'x'_0 + A'x'_1 + \cdots + A'x'_n$, $M' = A'x_1 + \cdots + A'x_n$, and $f':N'\to M'$ defined in an obvious way.

Comment: Looks good! Not the kind of proof I was looking for, but it fixes the gap in Orzech's.

Answer (score 10):

user26857's answer shows how to repair the reduction to the Noetherian case. Here is how to repair the proof of the Noetherian case:

> Let $M$ be a noetherian $A$-module and let $N \subseteq M$ be a submodule. Let $f : N \to M$ be a surjective linear map. Then $f$ is injective.

Proof: Let $n \geq 0$. Although $f^n$ is not a well-defined homomorphism this is a *partial* homomorphism, defined on the submodule $D_n = N \cap f^{-1}(N) \cap f^{-1}(f^{-1}(N)) \cap \dotsc \cap f^{-1}(f^{-1}(\dotsc))$ (intersection of $n$ submodules). Let $K_n \subseteq D_n$ be the kernel of $f^n$. Then $K_n \subseteq K_{n+1}$ for all $n$. Since $M$ is noetherian, there is some $n$ such that $K_n = K_{n+1}$. Let $x \in N$ with $f(x)=0$. Since $f$ is surjective, the same is true for $f^n : D_n \to M$. Choose some $y \in D_n$ with $x = f^n(y)$. Then $y \in D_{n+1}$ and actually $f^{n+1}(y)=0$, so that $x=f^n(y)=0$.

Comment: Thanks, but I understood this from Orzech's note -- I think he was abusing notation here.

Comment: Alright, then it's OK.

Answer (score 9):

I have now found [*A constructive proof of Orzech's theorem*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/orzech.pdf), which relies on the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: At the time Orzech proved his result Corollary 0.2 wasn't a "well-known" fact. (The references of the paper can help understanding why I'm saying this.) Moreover, Orzech's result has *not* been "mostly forgotten". It has some important consequences for free modules which were used freely (sic!), and in some sense the result became folklore.

Comment: @user26857: thanks; I have cut down on the historical remarks in the pdf, as I never seem to get those right. What I was trying to say is that the general $N \subseteq M$ case has rarely appeared in literature (when I tried to search for references in order to answer this very question, I found nothing that used the result in full generality). Usually, it is the $N = M$ case (and its consequences) that is being used, and that is *by now* well-known.

Comment: If this matters, I've used Orzech's result at least once on M.SE; see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/575019). (That deleted account was mine.)

Comment: FYI: part of your proof was used (by me) to settle [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2454062/) right here on MSE. I tried to give due credit, even though you released most of your writings (including this one) to the public domain. :-) In any case, I learned something new, so thanks for that!