# Do automorphisms of a finitely generated free module restrict to automorphisms on every invariant submodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a (commutative) ring (with 1) and $M$ a free and finitely generated $R$-module. Let $\gamma$ be an $R$-module automorphism of $M$. If $N\subset M$ is a submodule invariant under $\gamma$, then is $\gamma|_N$ an automorphism of $N$?

If this is false, are there reasonable conditions under which it would be true? (e.g., $R$ noetherian...etc?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes in all cases, even if $N$ is not finitely generated.

The case where $N$ is finitely generated is settled by Orzech's theorem; see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065786/is-orzechs-generalization-of-the-surjective-endomorphism-is-injective-theorem-c). (To reduce to said theorem, pass to $\gamma^{-1}$ instead of $\gamma$, which restricts to a surjective $R$-module homomorphism $N \supseteq \gamma(N) \to N$.) This question was [answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1066110) by user26857, the very same who already observed that the result holds if $N$ is only assumed to be finitely generated.

The general case is settled by using the Cayley–Hamilton theorem. I follow the approach taken by Darij Grinberg in [this writing](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/orzech.pdf), which was also linked in [his own answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1127237/) to the aforementioned question regarding Orzech's theorem. The key ingredient to Darij's writing is the following lemma (presented here in my own words):

> **Lemma 0.5.** *($A$ is a commutative ring with unit and $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ is given.) Let $g : A^n \to A^n$ be an $A$-linear map and let $V \subseteq A^n$ be a submodule satisfying $g^{-1}(V) \subseteq V$. Then we have $g(V) \subseteq V$.*
>
> *Proof.* The case $n = 0$ is trivial, but needs to be considered separately. For the remainder of this proof, we assume $n \geq 1$. By the Cayley–Hamilton theorem, we may choose some $c_0,\ldots,c_n\in A$ with $c_n = 1$ such that
>   $$ c_ng^n + c_{n-1}g^{n-1} + \cdots + c_1g + c_0 = 0.\tag*{(1)} $$
>   We prove by induction that every $u\in \{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ satisfies
>   $$ \big(c_ng^{n - u} + c_{n-1}g^{n - u - 1} + \cdots + c_{u+1}g + c_u\big)(V) \subseteq V.\tag*{(2)} $$
>
> - The base case $u = 0$ is clear from $(1)$.
> - Let $p \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ be given and suppose that $(2)$ holds for $u = p - 1$. We must now prove that it also holds for $u = p$. To that end, let $v\in V$ be given. By the induction hypothesis, we have
>     $$ \big(c_ng^{n - p + 1} + c_{n-1}g^{n - p} + \cdots + c_pg + c_{p-1}\big)(v) \in V. $$
>     Since we also have $c_{p-1}v \in V$, it follows that
>     \begin{align*}
>        &\: g\Big(\big(c_ng^{n - p} + c_{n-1}g^{n - p - 1} + \cdots + c_{p+1}g + c_p\big)(v)\Big)\\[1ex]
>        =& \: \Big(g\big(c_ng^{n - p} + c_{n-1}g^{n - p - 1} + \cdots + c_{p+1}g + c_p\big)\Big)(v)\\[1ex]
>        =& \: \big(c_ng^{n - p + 1} + c_{n-1}g^{n - p} + \cdots + c_{p+1}g^2 + c_pg\big)(v) \quad \in V.
>       \end{align*}
>     Therefore we have
>     $$ \big(c_ng^{n - p} + c_{n-1}g^{n - p - 1} + \cdots + c_{p+1}g + c_p\big)(v) \in g^{-1}(V) \subseteq V, $$
>     which shows that $(2)$ holds for $u = p$ as well.
>
> The proof shows that $(2)$ holds for all $u \in \{0,1,\ldots,n\}$, so in particular it holds for $u = n - 1$ (here we use the assumption $n \geq 1$). In other words, we have
>   $$ \big(c_ng + c_{n-1}\big)(V) \subseteq V. $$
>   Recall that $c_n = 1$ holds; therefore we find $g(V) \subseteq V$.$\quad\blacksquare$

Observe that the lemma cannot be reversed: there are ample examples where $g(V) \subseteq V$ holds but $g^{-1}(V) \not\subseteq V$. (Let $V = \langle x\rangle \subsetneq A$ be a proper principal ideal and let $g : A \to A$ be multiplication with $x$.)

To solve the problem at hand, we apply the above lemma to $g = \gamma^{-1}$ and $V = N$.

Comment: Nice use or my lemma! I am wondering if you have thought about the question at https://mathoverflow.net/a/275105/ and how a corresponding lemma might look like (an endomorphism of a finitely generated polynomial ring must fix a subring if the preimage of this subring is contained in itself?).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Hm, it seems that your lemma (and hence the entire solution) extends to the case that $M$ is only finitely generated, not necessarily free. The Cayley–Hamilton theorem still holds here (see e.g. Proposition 2.4 in Atiyah–MacDonald), which comes to show just how powerful it is!

Comment: Regarding your other question: no, I haven't thought about it. I might think about it some day, but not today. Thanks for bringing it to my attention anyway. :-)

Comment: Nice observation!

Answer (score 16):

If $R$ is Noetherian, this is true. Notice that $\gamma(N)\subset N$ implies $N\subset \gamma^{-1} N$. Thus, we get a chain $N\subset\gamma^{-1} N\subset \gamma^{-2} N\subset\cdots$ and by Noetherian hypothesis, we have $\gamma^{-n}(N)=\gamma^{-n-1}(N)$ for some $n$ and then it is easy to see that $N=\gamma(N)$, proving what you need.

Comment: By using a noetherian reduction I think we can only assume that $N$ is finitely generated in order to arrive at the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

This alternative solution is a bit simpler than my other answer.

**Proposition.** *Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit, and let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module (not necessarily free). Let $\gamma : M \to M$ be an $R$-module automorphism of $M$, and let $N \subseteq M$ be a submodule invariant under $\gamma$. Then $\gamma$ restricts to an automorphism of $N$.*

*Proof.* By assumption, we have $\gamma[N] \subseteq N$. We show that equality holds.

By Cayley–Hamilton, $\gamma^{-1}$ satisfies a monic polynomial
$$ \gamma^{-n} + a_1 \gamma^{-n+1} + \cdots + a_n \text{id} = 0. $$
Multiplying by $\gamma^n$, we find
$$ \text{id} + a_1 \gamma + \cdots + a_n \gamma^n = 0. $$
To prove $\gamma[N] \supseteq N$, note that for every $x \in N$ we have
$$ x = \text{id}(x) = (-a_1\gamma - \cdots - a_n\gamma^n)(x) \in \gamma[N].\tag*{$\Box$} $$

---

<sub>Acknowledgement: Raymond van Bommel and I found this solution together, a while ago. Thanks Raymond!</sub>