# Injection and surjection to a finite dimensional free module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, free-modules

Say you have a bimodule $M$ over a ring $A$ with maps $f,g:M \rightarrow A^n$ such that $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective. Can we say that $M \cong A^n$? What if $f$ and $g$ were in the opposite direction? What if $A$ is commutative?

I figured out that if the free module is infinite dimensional, then they need not be isomorphic, but can't figure out the finite dimensional case.

EDIT: I would welcome an answer even if it just answers the commutative case.

Comment: Since $g : M \to A^n$ is surjective and $A^n$ is free (thus projective), the surjection splits and we have $M \cong A^n \oplus \ker(g)$. Thus you need either to find a ring $A$ such that $A^n \oplus T$ injects into $A^n$ for some $A$-module $T \neq 0$ or show that this is not possible.

Comment: Yes, I did realize that, however, I couldn't proceed further.

Comment: You want $f$ and $g$ to be bimodule homomorphisms? And for $A^n$ to have the obvious bimodule structure given by left and right multiplication?

Comment: @JeremyRickard, yes. Although, I would like a partial answer with $M$ being a left module.

Comment: For left modules over a commutative ring $A$, this is true and follows from [Orzech's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065786/is-orzechs-generalization-of-the-surjective-endomorphism-is-injective-theorem-c) (since you can use the injective map $f$ to identify $M$ with a submodule of $A^n$).

Comment: The same holds for bimodules over a commutative ring $A$. Indeed, $A$-$A$-bimodules are "the same as" left modules over the commutative ring $A\otimes_{\mathbb Z}A^{\operatorname{op}}$, and of course you can apply Orzech's theorem over the latter ring as well. (The $A\otimes_{\mathbb Z}A^{\operatorname{op}}$-module $A$ is not usually free, but it is finitely generated, and that's sufficient.)

Comment: Thanks! That does answer that part of my question. Feel free to add that as an answer.