# $n+1$ elements in the free module $R^n$ must be linear dependent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Suppose that $R$ is a nonzero commutative ring with unit, and $R^n$ is the free module of dimension $n$ over $R$. Is it right that  $n+1$ elements in $R^n$ must be linearly dependent?

Comment: Yes. This is true. In fact, something more general is true. If $M$ is an $R$-module that can be generated by $n$ elements, then any $n+1$ elements are linearly dependent. This is question 2) in this [MSE post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574653/infinite-linear-independent-family-in-a-finitely-generated-a-module). While this answers your question completely in affirmative (because $R^{n}$ can be generated by $n$ elements), I think there might be a simpler argument in the special case when $M=R^{n}$ is a free module, so I will not vote to close (as a duplicate) for now.

Comment: If $R$ is a domain, you can include it in its quotient field and use that this fact is true for fields.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan True. However, I have a question about the term "domain". On [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_(ring_theory)), mathematicians don't require a domain to be commutative, but we need the commutativity of multiplication of the ring $R$ to define its quotient field $Q(R)$. Is your "domain" commutative or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that there are $n+1$ linearly independent elements $x_1, x_2, …, x_{n+1}$ in $M=R^{n}$. Consider the submodule $F$ generated by these $n+1$ elements. Then clearly $F\cong R^{n+1}$. Since $F$ is a submodule of $M=R^{n}$, it follows that there is an injective $R$-linear map $R^{n+1}\to R^{n}$. But this is impossible!

That there is no injective $R$-linear map from $R^{n+1}\to R^{n}$ follows from this (famous?) exercise in Atiyah & Macdonald's commutative algebra textbook (Exercise 2.11). See this [Mathoverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136/atiyah-macdonald-exercise-2-11/47846#47846). Let me copy the statement of the exercise and a beautiful solution (given by Balasz Strenner) for convenience.

**Proposition.** If $A$ is a nonzero commutative ring with $1$, and there is an injective $A$-linear map $A^{m}\to A^{n}$, then $m\leq n$.

**Proof.** Assume by contradiction that there is an injective map $\phi: A^m \to A^n$ with $m>n$. The first idea is that we regard $A^n$ as a submodule of $A^m$, say the submodule generated by the first $n$ coordinates. Then, by the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem (Proposition 2.4 in Atiyah & Macdonald), $\phi$ satisfies some polynomial equation
\begin{equation}
\phi^k + a_{k-1} \phi^{k-1} + \cdots + a_1 \phi + a_0 = 0.
\end{equation}
Using the injectivity of $\phi$ it is easy to see that if this polynomial has the minimal possible degree, then $a_0 \ne 0$. But then, applying this polynomial of $\phi$ to $(0,\ldots,0, 1)$, the last coordinate will be $a_0$ which is a contradiction as it should be zero.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I should read Atiyah's textbook for more details.

Comment: @XiangYu You are welcome! Yes, I'd highly recommend Atiyah & Macdonald's book to learn commutative algebra. And try doing most of the exercises. There are some gems in the exercises. For example, already in Chapter 1, one of the exercises outlines a remarkable proof for the existence of algebraic closure (due to Emil Artin). While this particular exercise is not really about commutative algebra, I think such exercises are very enriching.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574653/infinite-linear-independent-family-in-a-finitely-generated-a-module/575019#575019

Comment: @user26857: Indeed. I had posted the link in the comments to the question already. Orzech's result is pretty powerful